# Hide specifics divs by matching sub-elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a....small code in order to hide 4 divs in a list using a predefined text. These divs are actually a list of categories, they have a img sub-element and an anchor with text. I know the title of the anchors and the images but I couldn't figure out yet how to hide the entire div based on matching its sub-elements.

Here is how the structure looks like

```
<div class="cp"> 
    <div class="cp">
        <div class="cp">
            <div class="image">
                <a class="catv2">
                    <img src="http://example.com/image/categories/shell.jpg" title="shell" alt="shell">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="name">
                <a id="link-cat-big" class="catv2" title="Shell case parts">Shell</a>       
            </div>
            <div class="cp">
```

In the above example I know the "shell" category, that's what I want to hide.

How can I hide one or more `<div class="cp">` by matching either the sub-elements title, alt or text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('[title*="shell"]').closest('.cp').hide();
```

or

```
$('[title*="shell"]').parents('.cp').hide()
```

Answer (score -1):

HIDES THE DIV ELEMENT. **DOESN'T TAKE SPACE**

```
div{
    display:none;
}
```

HIDES THE DIV BUT **DOES TAKE SPACE**

```
div{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Not just that, but it doesn't answer the question.